# justify content center within modal not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the justify-content-center within a modal but for some it does not render like it should..

I am trying to render a button in the middle of a div

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static "images/manager_happy.png"%}" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h5>Improve your managerial skills by understanding who is in your team</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                  <div class="price-modal-container">
                    <span class="modal-price-title">Price:</span><span class="modal-price">60$</span><span class="modal-Oprice">299$</span><span class="modal-discount">60% off</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="time-price">
                    <i class="far fa-clock fa-spin"></i>Limited time offer discount
                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
              <a href="{% url 'website:payment' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btnsmallfont" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>  Add Credit Now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <a href="{% url 'website:payment' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btnsmallfont" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>  Add Credit Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea it does not work ? is there any trouble because of the modal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to render it so the button is horizontally centered?  Right now it's not working because the `col` class takes up all the remaining width.  So you can either make the content inside the column centered or make it so the column itself doesn't take up the full width.

To center the content inside the column you just need add the `text-center` class either to the column or by simply replacing `justify-content-center` on the row.

```
<div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col">
      <a href="{% url 'website:payment' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btnsmallfont" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>  Add Credit Now</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can keep the row the way it is and change the column class from `col` to `col-auto` so it won't take the full width.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-auto">
      <a href="{% url 'website:payment' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btnsmallfont" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>  Add Credit Now</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example it's trivial because the column is filled with a single button so the effect is the same.  If you had something like multiple lines of text that don't take up the width of the row then the first example would center the text, whereas the second example would keep the original text alignment but center the box that contains the text.